# Update azure api inbound policy from powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, policy, inbound

Firstly Thanks for looking into this.

I've a requirement to update the inbound policy of an API managed by Azuremanagementservice from powershell. For this I have tried accessing the API from powershell unfortunately ended up at no progress.

What I am looking for via powershell
a) Access API under AzuremanagementService
b) Update the inbound operation policy

Thanks

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set policies by Azure PowerShell, try the code below(adding a root level inbound IP block policy for demo):

```
$newPolicy = '<policies>
                <inbound>
                    <ip-filter action="forbid">
                        <address-range from="192.168.0.1" to="192.168.0.2" />
                    </ip-filter>
                </inbound>
                <backend>
                    <forward-request />
                </backend>
                <outbound />
                <on-error />
             </policies>'

$apim_context = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>" -ServiceName "<API management service name>"

Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apim_context  -Policy $newPolicy
```

Result:
[image]

For more about `Set-AzApiManagementPolicy` operations, please see [this reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-5.3.0).

**UPDATE**

If you want to modify the policy at API level, you need to use command below to get all `ApiId`:

```
Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $apim_context | Select-Object Name,ApiId
```

[image]

I specify the ApiID as "echo-api":

```
Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apim_context  -Policy $newPolicy -ApiId 'echo-api'
```

Result:
[image]

For more about set policy using PowerShell, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-5.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-2.6.0).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am looking to change for a specific API under that API Management Service.

Comment: @user14846304, I have uploaded my answer about how to modify policy on API level. Could you please lick the mark icon beside my answer to accept it if my post solves your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the REST API:
[Api Operation Policy - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apioperationpolicy/createorupdate)

PUT [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/apis/{apiId}/operations/{operationId}/policies/policy?api-version=2019-12-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/%7BserviceName%7D/apis/%7BapiId%7D/operations/%7BoperationId%7D/policies/policy?api-version=2019-12-01)

Comment: Thanks Markus for your time on this.