# How to add a log-to-eventhub policy to an Azure API Management Policy using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, azure-eventhub

I would like to add a policy to an Azure API Management API using terraform

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub" "my-event-hub" {
  name                = "my-logger"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.my-events.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myresourcegroup.name
  partition_count     = 2
  message_retention   = 1
}
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "eventhub-policy" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.my-apim.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.my-api.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myresourcegroup.name

  xml_content = <<XML
  <policies>s
    <inbound>
       <log-to-eventhub logger-id="my-logger">@{
         return new JObject(
            #***** json objects here *********#
         ).ToString();
         }</log-to-eventhub>
     <base />
     <set-backend-service base-url="https://my-stub.getsandbox.com" />
   </inbound>
  <backend>
      <base />
  </backend>
  <outbound>
      <base />
  </outbound>
  <on-error>
      <base />
  </on-error>
</policies>
XML
}
```

I can create this policy through the portal. I can create the APIM instance and the API using terraform, but when I try to create the policy I get the following validation error:

> │ Error: creating or updating API Policy ...: apimanagement.APIPolicyClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="ValidationError" Message="One or more fields contain incorrect values:" Details=[{"code":"ValidationError","message":"Error in element 'log-to-eventhub' on line 3, column 11: **Log to EventHub only accepts Logger Type of azureEventHub"**,"target":"log-to-eventhub"}]

Can anyone suggest how I match the policy to the created event hub?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Set-AzApiManagementPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-6.3.0#example-3--set-api-scope-policy)** PowerShell command to set API-scope policy for API Management.

```
Set-AzApiManagementPolicy
   -Context <PsApiManagementContext>
   [-Format <String>]
   -ApiId <String>
   [-ApiRevision <String>]
   -OperationId <String>
   [-Policy <String>]
   [-PolicyFilePath <String>]
   [-PolicyUrl <String>]
   [-PassThru]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "Api-Default-WestUS" -ServiceName "contoso"
Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId "9876543210" -Policy $PolicyString
```

You can refer to GitHub closed issue at [Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy does not show validation errors](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/5386#issuecomment-494491188) and open issue at [How to update API Policy?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14695).

Other references: [How to log events to Azure Event Hubs in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs) and [Update azure api inbound policy from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602542/update-azure-api-inbound-policy-from-powershell)